# assign function don't assign an array to an object

Tags: php

I've been working on a register system and i'm doing the registration part now , but i keep getting errors like "username" can't be null or other errors from db fields.

After some debugging i founded out that if i try to show the params i called the function with i get them in function.

Function call :

```
        $newUser->registerNewUser($_POST);
```

And for debug i created a basic function called dnd

```
 function dnd($data) //debug function
 {
  echo '<pre>';
 var_dump($data);
  echo '</pre>';
    die();
 }
```

And then , there we have the register new user function

```
 public function registerNewUser($params)
  {

     $this->assign($params);
       dnd($params);
    $this->deleted = 0;
    $this->password = password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $this->save();
  }
```

The dnd($params) returns me this :

```
   array(6) {
     ["fname"]=>
     string(8) "Fnamegood"
      ["lname"]=>
       string(9) "Lnamegood"
      ["email"]=>
  string(18) "email@gmail.com"
  ["username"]=>
  string(8) "infernus"
  ["password"]=>
  string(7) "workingpassword"
  ["confirm"]=>
  string(7) "workingpassword"
    }
```

And after i assign , the array is empty.

Before assign :

```
object(Users)#13 (16) {
  ["_isLoggedIn":"Users":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_sessionName":"Users":private]=>
  string(21) "GJdsadaHsdahgFGDasdaS"
  ["_cookieName":"Users":private]=>
  string(24) "nfbfbfafusibfsau548a484f"
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
  ["username"]=>
  NULL
  ["email"]=>
  NULL
  ["password"]=>
  NULL
  ["fname"]=>
  NULL
  ["lname"]=>
  NULL
  ["acl"]=>
  NULL
  ["deleted"]=>
  NULL
  etc ..
```

And after the assign it looks like

```
object(Users)#13 (17) {
  ["_isLoggedIn":"Users":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_sessionName":"Users":private]=>
  string(21) "GJdsadaHsdahgFGDasdaS"
  ["_cookieName":"Users":private]=>
  string(24) "nfbfbfafusibfsau548a484f"
 ["id"]=>
  NULL
  ["username"]=>
  NULL
  ["email"]=>
  NULL
  ["password"]=>
  NULL
  ["fname"]=>
  NULL
  ["lname"]=>
  NULL
  ["acl"]=>
  NULL
  ["deleted"]=>
  NULL
 etc..
```

And the assign function look like

```
 public function assign ($params)
     {
       if(!empty($params))
       {
        foreach ($params as $key => $val)
        {
          if(in_array($key, $this->_columnNames))
          {
            $this->key = sanitize($val);
          }
        }
        return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
```

And the sanitize

```
function sanitize($dirty)
{
   return htmlentities($dirty, ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: Can u write what does the `assign` function do?

Comment: @harry i added it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the assign function 
It should be like this

```
public function assign($params)
      {
        if(!empty($params)) {
          foreach($params as $key => $val) {
            if(property_exists($this,$key)){
              $this->$key = sanitize($val);
            }
          }
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is mixing properties, even private ones, with unfiltered `$_POST` keys. What does happen when an attacker sends `?_isLoggedIn=1&_sessionName=abc&_cookieName=xyz`? At least an unexpected error could occur, possibly exposing internal information. No whitelist or separate key/value storage present here. `property_exists($this,$key = '_isLoggedIn')` is `true`.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone the sanitize function fix it

Comment: It tries to sanitize the **value** but the **key**.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone u are right but u can't pass the question as he did another post a few days ago and he have an table with user_sessions and you can't pass the login

Comment: It should be recommended to introduce `private $post_vars` using `__get` and `__set` or at least to check whether or not property names begin with an underscore and strictly name private properties with the underscore prefix by convention. I guess the `_columnNames` property was just not properly implemented in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

You need the line $this->key to read $this->$key

That's assuming that $this->_columnNames exists and has values, etc...

Answer (score 0):

you may chech if $params is array with 'is_array' function.

```
 public function assign ($params)
     {
       if(!empty($params)**&&is_array($params))**
      ....
```